# PHP- years and months array keys and inside values sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is an php array representing years and months:

```
array:3 [
  2017 => array:2 [
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
  ]
  2018 => array:2 [
    0 => "1"
    1 => "5"
  ]
  2019 => array:3 [
    0 => "10"
    1 => "12"
    2 => "6"
  ]
]
```

I want to sort it on the basis of key (descending) on first level and values (descending) on the second level. by this records of latest month in latest year will appear. So the output must be:

```
array:3 [
  2019 => array:3 [
      0 => "12"
      1 => "10"
      2 => "6"
    ]
  2018 => array:2 [
      0 => "5"
      1 => "1"
  ]
  2017 => array:2 [
    0 => "3"
    1 => "2"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a question of applying [`krsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) to the top-level of the array and [`rsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) to each sub-level:

```
krsort($array);
array_walk($array, function (&$v) { rsort($v); });
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 6
        )
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
        )
    [2017] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6WW9a)

Comment: i edited the question. because i was actually sorting an array containing records of years and months. now latest record will appear first.